# What was the argument about between the different muslims when Uthman (R.A) united them?

Tags: quran, uloom-al-quran, preservation

I know there was an argument between the Muslims in the subject of Quran at the time of Uthman (R.A). **What was the argument about**? Did the Muslims not agree that other recitations were correct ? And if so, Uthman (R.A) still left the marks and vowels out so that wouldnt solve the matter. I am so confused, please let me know.

Comment: Who are these ”some” who made either of the claims?

Comment: This already is wrong, and such an information should be added to your post (edit and add it please) not posted in a comment, but still the strangest of your claims is missing.

Comment: My main problem is to know what was the dialect of Quryesh and if the additions to the text made any effect to the Quran that was to be sent to the other areas?

Comment: They disagreed in their recitations, and the recitations at the time had large differences between them (different synonyms, different order of words, etc.) even if not ultimately in the message. The writing of the mushaf, even if it let there be some differences due to the lack of marks, removed the vast majority of differences, and now there was a reference for people to look to if they differed in a major way. Uthman (RA) felt that the Sahabah could tolerate major differences as they were knowledgeable but other people couldn't.

Comment: Thank you so much! Jazak Allah for the clarification! Did these differences existed due to the Ahruf or the misunderstanding of the people?

Comment: @KhizerKhan There were different "styles/dialects" of recitations of the Quran that were spread around (based on the Ahruf), they usually were localized to certain regions, so when other people who haven't heard such recitations (especially those in the new Muslim lands) heard them for the first time, arguments rose on who was correct, until they were unified into a codex.

Comment: Jazak Allah! Everything seems so clear now. Thank you!

Comment: @TheZ I wanted to ask if Uthman (R.A) purposely left out the marks to accomodate other Qiraat?

Comment: Yes. That is what I have heard.

Comment: Heard from where? Any reliable source please?